# Could a loose galactic alliance be dismantled in a quick coup?

Tags: internal-consistency, geopolitics, empire-building, diplomacy, galactic

In my book series (link [here](http://sites.google.com/site/weaselworldofficialsite)), the planets of Aurea, Ishgabangaloodoo, and most of the eastern half of the galaxy have entered an alliance against the Tatian Empire (Caput Tatiium and most of the western half of the galaxy). Weasel, the King of Aurea, is the leader of the alliance, and Tate is the leader of the Tatian Empire. However, things take a dark turn when Tate invades the planet of Awal Kabab, right on Aurea's doorstep. Confident he can defeat the smaller Tatian force, Weasel sends the entire garrison of Aurea to fight the Tatians on Awal Kabab. Although the Alliance wins a smashing but pyrrhic victory, it was a trap: Tate landed on the undefended Aurea with the bulk of their army.

Here's what needs to happen next: Now that Tate is on Aurea with an army behind him and the Alliance army is too tired and weakened from their pyrrhic victory to simply go back to Aurea and kick him out, Tate wants to take more-or-less complete control of the alliance and end the war. Here's specifically what needs to happen:

- He must take control of the Alliance Military and add it to his own
- He must successfully declare himself Emperor of the Tatian Galaxy (a new empire spanning the entire galaxy)
- He must use the new army he suddenly acquired to rapidly (as in within a few weeks) to occupy the rest of the galaxy
- Weasel and his friends must all be declared enemies of the state and forced into hiding (think order 66 from ROTS but only a few are killed)
- Tate must convince the galaxy's citizens that he is a more legitimate ruler than the old alliance

Now here's my question: Could Tate pull off a coup like this, and under what conditions would this be allowed to happen?

Comment: If George Lucas got away with it in the Eps 1-3 trilogy, so can you.

Comment: If the alliance is a loose coalition, does Tate need to end up in control of it, or is it sufficient that it breaks apart into its individual member-states?

Comment: @Cadence Tate is a power-hungry space conqueror. He wants complete control of the galaxy, and the opportunity just handed itself to him on a silver platter. He wants total control of the alliance.

Comment: @Renan Black Panther is a better analogy, An outsider coming in and taking control of an entire country (with a insider backing him).

Answer (score 3):

**To pull this off, Tate needs to have friends on Aurea.**

The Aurean army might be tired after their battle but the Aurean homeworld is not.  The people there barely knew there was a battle going on.  How is a "small force" showing up going to take control of a nation?  How will they govern?  What will prevent total chaos?

The only way for Tate to show up unannounced and rule Aurea on short notice is to use 99.44% of the governance structures already in place.  Fortunately, the prior leader (can he be named Whale Kebab?  Or is that too close to the planet?) ousted by King Weasel is ready to come out of hiding and introduce Tate as a liberating hero.  W.K. correctly figures that King Tate will hold some parades, receive some love and then move on to his next endeavor leaving Prime Minister W.K. de facto king.

Weasel knows how the dice roll.  He will thank his men and send them home, pack up his closest advisors and get scarce.